# Why does the connection to ASE fail when password encryption is required?

Tags: php, sap-ase

How can I password encrypt the database server connections from PHP to Sybase ASE?

The PHP connection to ASE fails when `net password encryption reqd = 1`.

How can we make a PHP DB connection to ASE with password encryption? Is there a PHP keyword or parameter that we need to set on the client side connection?

Comment: I have been using Sybase from PHP for years now, but I have never seen any way to do what you are asking for

Comment: I have ran into this posting here http://ccit.college.columbia.edu/knowledgebase/article/setting-sybase-ct-with-encrypted-password-connections-linux-using-ase-15.php and might be a possible solution

Comment: This is what Sybase support said.You might be able workaround the problem by using an ocs.cfg file.
In your $SYBASE/OCS-15_0/config directory the is a sample.cfg file.

vi the sample.cfg file and add this line to the Default section

[DEFAULT]
     CS_SEC_ENCRYPTION = CS_TRUE

This might work.
If the application is passing a name, you would create a new section

[application name]
     CS_SEC_ENCRYPTION = CS_TRUE

The Sybase person also said that you should be using at least Sybase Version 15.7.

Comment: I suggest you repeat what you wrote as a full-fledged answer, you might get some deserved credit points, and your answer will be more accessible to people with the same problem. Answerings one's own question is ok, as long as it is not a trick for gathering credit points.

Comment: sorry, not credit points, but reputation points (or votes)

Comment: I am still testing.  Getting closer.  Once I have a solution I'll put out answer to my question.

Comment: Hi Walter.  Would you like to help answer to my new question in term of Sybase, PHP, and Apache?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457342/how-could-i-get-apache-to-support-php-5-3-6-connecting-to-sybase-ase-15-7

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution to this problem in term of able to connect from a Linux 64 bit base machine with PHP version 5.3.6 and Sybase driver from Sybase CTISQL `Utility/15.7/P-EBF19975 ESD #3/DRV.15.7.0.3`. While we got this to work, we need to have Apache to work in addition to this, I am hoping Sybase support is able to help us with that as well as they have with solution below to our question. I am posting this here for everyone benefit.  Note: AFAICT, this is not a supported solution by Sybase.  Please use it as your own risk.

Few things need to happen for this to work:

1. I've use the latest Debian Stable 6.05 squeeze 64 bit
2. I've install ebf19977(developer kit with open client, yes the number is off, that's not a mistake, you will see when you install it) downloaded from Sybase
3. Download PHP 5.3.6 from php.net website to be compile from source.

**Step 1)**  I am assume one should easily set this up.  Make sure you have sudo access

**Step 2)**  To install the developer kit you need to type the whole path to where the setup.bin file is locate like so type in sudo /home/btran/ebf19977/setup.bin , this will start the setup, pretty much follow instructions there to to install OpenClient and its associate tools.  Make sure that Open Client, and PHP library are install.

Once you done the install there are a few other steps to do:

Set all Sybase environments variables by executing the SYBASE.sh in the root directory at /opt/sybase

```
sudo cat /opt/sybase/SYBASE.sh >> /etc/profile , if necessary source /etc/profile
```

This will set most of the variables, but you need to add a couple variable that is not there:

```
    PHPRC=/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/config
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib
```

Your /ect/profile should look something like this:

```
    # ------------------------------------
    #    Sybase Product Environment variables
    # ------------------------------------
    SYBASE="/opt/sybase"
    export SYBASE
    SYBASE_OCS="OCS-15_0"
    export SYBASE_OCS
    INCLUDE="/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/include":$INCLUDE
    export INCLUDE
    LIB="/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib":$LIB
    export LIB
    PATH="/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/bin":$PATH
    export PATH
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib3p64:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib3p":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

    PHPRC="/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/config"
    export PHPRC

    JAVA_HOME="/opt/sybase/jre32"
    export JAVA_HOME

    RIBO_HOME="/opt/sybase/jutils-3_0/ribo"
    export RIBO_HOME
    # ------------------------------------
```

Then, you will also need to made modification to the interfaces file located at root directory /opt/sybase to look something like this, please do not use this, use your info:

```
    dev
        master tcp ether dev.company.com 4425
        query tcp ether dev.company.com 4425

    prod
        master tcp ether prod.company.com 4425
        query tcp ether prod.company.com 4425

    ribo
        master tcp ether testhost.company.com 5005
        query tcp ether testhost.company.com 5005
```

You will also need to made modification to the ocs.cfg to get PHP to initiated correctly, this located in the folder `/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/config` to look like this:

```
    ;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; This is the default external configuration definition file. Feel free
    ; to add your own customizations.
    ;
    [DEFAULT]
    ; This is the default section loaded by applications that use
    CS_SEC_ENCRYPTION = CS_TRUE
    [ANSI_ESQL]
    ; This section defines configuration which an ANSI conforming
    CS_CAP_RESPONSE = CS_RES_NOSTRIPBLANKS
    CS_EXTRA_INF = CS_TRUE
    CS_ANSI_BINDS = CS_TRUE
    CS_OPT_ANSINULL = CS_TRUE
    CS_OPT_ANSIPERM = CS_TRUE
    CS_OPT_STR_RTRUNC = CS_TRUE
    CS_OPT_ARITHABORT = CS_FALSE
    CS_OPT_TRUNCIGNORE = CS_TRUE
    CS_OPT_ARITHIGNORE = CS_FALSE
    CS_OPT_ISOLATION = CS_OPT_LEVEL3
    CS_OPT_CHAINXACTS = CS_TRUE
    CS_OPT_CURCLOSEONXACT = CS_TRUE
    CS_OPT_QUOTED_IDENT = CS_TRUE
    ; End of default sections

    [isql]
    CS_SEC_ENCRYPTION = CS_TRUE

    [PHP]
    CS_SEC_ENCRYPTION = CS_TRUE

    ; This is a sample section showing how you might alter configuration
    ; properties for you Embedded SQL application.
    [SAMPLE_ESQL]
    ; use most of the ANSI properties defined above
    include = ANSI_ESQL
    ; but override some default properties
    CS_OPT_CHAINXACTS = CS_FALSE ; run in autocommit mode
    ;;;;;;;;;
```

Note: Very Critical to check for the existence of the php.ini file in the same directory as well `/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/config` (this pointing the exention file, look at the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib`)

you php.ini should read like this:

```
    extension=/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib/sybaseasephp.so
```

**Step 3)** compile PHP from source, again Sybase call for 64 bit.

I down load the source to `/opt/php-5.3.6` for persistent with where most app install for Linux.

```
    cd to /opt/php-5.3.6 

    ./configure
```

**VERY IMPORTANT** to note, this is where we ran into a snag, if I choose any other configure option and not default ./configure, PHP will fail to load with error below:

```
btran@sls-baonix:/opt/php-5.3.6$ php ~/test-dev.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib/sybaseasephp.so' -
/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib/sybaseasephp.so: undefined
symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sybase_connect() in
/home/btran/test-dev.php on line 10
]
```

Reason we need other options is we need it also to work with Apache.  We got it now to work with PHP, but we need to be able to initiate PHP from website so the dependencies is that PHP beside support Sybase, it also need to support Apache.  If any PHP expert out there has solution to this please jump in and help us out.