# How could I get Apache to support PHP 5.3.6 connecting to Sybase ASE 15.7?

Tags: php, apache, debian, sap-ase

Referencing to my previous question below, where I am able to get PHP to talk to SYBASE ASE 15.7:

[Why does the connection to ASE fail when password encryption is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144100/php-why-connection-to-ase-fails-when-password-encryption-required)

As, I have mentioned, we ran into a little snag so I am posting another question here mean while making effort to resolve it ASAP, anyone has the expertise, please share.  Of course, once we're able to figure it out, will share answer here as well.

What I am look to do is similar to these couple postings below:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Sybase-PHP-Apache/index.html

http://sybase-addict.com/2010/01/16/sybase-ase-v15-apache-and-php-compilation/

But with the latest apache version, PHP 5.3.6, and connecting to Sybase ASE 15.7.  Also, we are running Debian squeeze stable.  Probably folks out there from Sybase may be the best bet to answer to this question.  So please help as appropriate.

-We have success with PHP 5.3.6 talking to Sybase ASE.
-We have success with PHP talking to Apache

But not both.

Key components I guess to be successful is knowing which ./configure PHP options to use and Sybase's specific library linking.  Those above links have similar to what we are looking for, but every time, I've try compile with any other options beside the default ./configure I would get error below:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib/sybaseasephp.so' -
/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/php/php536_64/lib/sybaseasephp.so: undefined
symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0

Any PHP/SYBASE expert out there know the answer to this, please share.

Best,

Bao

Comment: So I follow the guide at by sybase addict. After went through some serious time compiling apache from source and all the snag from the apr, apr-util, and pcre, got that resolve. Move on with the PHP installation hit another snage. It appear to be something to do with 32 vs 64 bit version of PHP, but I am not quite sure. I get complaint below after "make" saying: "/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib/libsybtcl.so when searching for -lsybtcl /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsybtcl collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [libphp5.la] Error 1"

Comment: I should also add that below is ./configure option I've use. `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php/php-5.3.6 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/httpd/apache-2.4.2/bin/apxs --with-sybase-ct=/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0 --with-config-file-path=/etc`

Comment: Got suggestion to try this php configure option instead `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php/php-5.3.6 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/httpd/apache-2.4.2/bin/apxs --with-sybase-sybct64=/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0 --with-config-file-path=/etc` 
Configure was success but with Notice: unknown option --with-sybase-sybct64=/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0.  Try run make anyway.  That was also success.  But same PHP warning of unable to load sybase dynamic library come back as originally posted.